# Join Operation using index defined?

Tags: mysql, index-tuning, mariadb, optimization, tokudb, query-performance

I need to optimize some queries with several joins. I plan to create some indexes for these queries.

I am currently using MariaDB with TokuDB storage engine.

Should I expect the indexes for the join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TokuDB is a storage engine in MariaDB, as is XtraDB/Aria/MyISAM. Queries are planned by the upper layers of MariaDB (and MySQL) calling into the storage engine to help it make decisions about optimization.

What you need to do is

1. create your tables and load your data
2. create the indexes you think will help optimize your query workload
3. run your queries with EXPLAIN

The EXPLAIN output will help you see that good decisions are made based on your indexes.

Comment: Use standard MySQL best practices. Whatever you'd do to create appropriate indexes for your queries in InnoDB or MyISAM applies to TokuDB as well.